# Adding a sparse series to a 'dense' dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to add a sparse series (column) to a "dense" data frame.  i.e. I would like to get something like the following to work.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c_1':['a', 'b', 'c'], 'n_1': [1., 2., 3.]})
df['new_column'] = pd.Series([0, 0, 1]).to_sparse(fill_value=0)
# AssertionError: Shape of new values must be compatible with manager shape
```

If we remove the to_sparse() then this works as expected.

Is there a way of combining a dense df with a sparse series?

Edit: Using pandas version 0.14.0-np18py27_0 on anaconda / win x64

Comment: show your pandas version

Comment: I built the dev version of pandas and I still get the same problem.  However, after building this: pd.version.short_version is still only '0.14.1'. I would have expected '0.15'?

Comment: hmm, a bug atm; though this was working ok, track the issue here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8131